# How to make a TextView act as a button in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, textview

I want a TextView to respond to click and open a second Activity.The Main Activity contains two text fields, a button and another TextView, which needs to act as a button.This code results in crashing of the App whenever it is run.

[image: MainActivity of the App]

Here is the MainActivity.java file.-

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
public void onSignUpClick(View view){
t1.setOnClickListener(
        new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(".SignUpActivity");
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
);
}
}
```

Here is the AndroidManifest.xml file.-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.abinas.myapplication">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".SignUpActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are calling onSignUpClick from you XML it should be as simple as:

```
public void onSignUpClick(View view){
   Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SignUpActivity.class);
   startActivity(intent);            
}
```

Alternatively you could just create the listener when activity is created:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView t1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);

        t1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SignUpActivity.class);
                 startActivity(intent); 

            }
        }           
        );

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

What's the error? Try changin your Intent for this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SignUpActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the `Intent` to something with this structure:

```
new Intent( current class.this, target activity.class)
```

In the code it should look like:

```
  public void onSignUpClick(View view){
    t1.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SignUpActivity.class)
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
    );
```

Comment: Please add details about the changes required.

Answer (score 1):

All the view widgets can override onclick method, but you are doing wrong you are using onclick method inside of another onclick method, and another thing is you should use findViewById inside onCreate method.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

TextView t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
t1.setOnClickListener(
      new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             Intent intent = new Intent(context,SignUpActivity.class);
             startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
);
 }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move this code inside your onCreate

```
TextView t1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    t1.setOnClickListener(
        new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(".SignUpActivity");
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
  );
}
```

Comment: Moving the onclicklistener inside onCreate in not necessary , i guess

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap you text view inside a linear layout and make the linear layout clickable.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear_forgot_password"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_small"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/btn_enter"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_enter">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_forgot_password"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        tools:text="Forgot password?"
         />
</LinearLayout>
```

An then get the onclick event in you activity or fragment.

Comment: No this is not necessary. A `TextView` is capable of handling `onClick` events.